# Java Login Interface That Displays Different Help Over Tries

Tags: java, authentication

I'm trying to write a Java login that shows different clues about the password. On the first try say: "It's a word"; In the second attempt say "It is a fruit"; etc...

What is the most efficient way to do this?

```
private void jBLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
char clave[]=jPass1.getPassword();
String clavedef=new String(clave);
if (jUsser.getText().equals("root") && clavedef.equals("apple")){
    this.dispose();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU CAN PASS", "AL", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    Alarm a = new Alarm();
    a.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    /**a function that adds 1 to the counter and shows the corresponding label ??*/

}
```

I suppose it could be done with a counter displaying different labels with `label1.setVisible(true)`;  but I do not know how to write the code. Thanks for the help

Comment: Interesting question, but the premise may have a flaw.  Typically password reminders are chosen by the user and are user specific.  Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: i'd rather change the text everytime than hide or display different labels. Also, Stack Overflow is **NOT** a code writing service, you should try some tutorials (do not ask for such here too), which you'll find plenty by doing some research.

Comment: No. The instructions are already saved in the system.

Comment: Thanks for the TIP. I just want ideas for a efficient way to manage it.